# Going back in a CSV file in python

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file like which is like this :

```
name, init
Tim Keller, TK
Nick Fill, NK
```

And here's what I want, somebody enter like `TK` and I will give him back `Hello Tim Keller !`

The only issue I have is I can't fallback in my CSV file (Well.. I don't know how to do it..)

Here's what I made :

```
with open('datas.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
                for columns in row:
                        if columns == args[i]:
                                print "Hello ", columns, " !"
```

Well with that code if the user enter `TK` I will print back `Hello TK !`

I tried something like `columns-1` but seems not to be like it..

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            for columns in row:
```

is not necessary. If you do for row in spamreader, you *already* have both parts, just index row: `row[0]` is the name, `row[1]` is the nickname.

See the [fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data your separator is a comma (`,`), or possibly a comma followed by a space. It's not clear what the quote char is, but I'd leave it as the default.

Also, I assume that the CSV file contains multiple lines like this:

```
name,init
Tim Keller,TK
Nick Fill,NK
```

The code to process this file would be like this:

```
import csv

search_initials = raw_input('Enter initials: ').strip()
with open('datas.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for name, initials in csv.reader(csvfile):
        if initials == search_initials:
            print "Hello {}!".format(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be clearer to not put the row into a "row" variable but into *two* more meaningful variables:

```
for name, init in spamreader:
    if init == args[i]:
        print "Hello ", name, " !"
```